# Jenkins Pipeline withCredentials with user scoped credentials

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I defined my user credential (username/password) in my jenkins profile ( Dashboard > USERID >
Credentials > User > Global credentials (unrestricted) )

But when I run the pipeline as follows, I get an error. It works if the credential is from the System (not user)

```
withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'CRED_ID', usernameVariable: 'aUser', passwordVariable: 'aPassword')]) {  
some code  
}
```

```
WARNING: Unknown parameter(s) found for class type 'org.jenkinsci.plugins.credentialsbinding.impl.StringBinding': passwordVariable,usernameVariable
```

```
ERROR: Could not find credentials entry with ID 'CRED_ID'
```

Does withCredentials support user context credentials?

Jenkins is version 2.414.1
Credentials Binding Plugin Version642.v737
Credentials Plugin Version1319.v7

Comment: This is not directly supported but you can achieve something similar using [the following guide](https://docs.cloudbees.com/docs/cloudbees-ci/latest/pipelines/user-scoped-creds).

Comment: @NoamHelmer : Thanks for this link. I found it earlier and this information used with the https://github.com/jenkinsci/ssh-steps-plugin  , allowed me to SSH to a remote from within Jenkins Pipeline.

Comment: More info in https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-44772